# Ubuntu wakes from suspend immediately

Tags: suspend, power-management

I've just recently gotten Ubuntu and have a problem with the suspend state. Whenever I put my PC into suspend, it will wake itself just 1 second later. I've already looked around and figured out that when you can see which devices can wake your PC from suspend using
`cat /proc/acpi/wakeup`. By trial and error I figured out that when I disable `GPP0` and `PTXH` my computer stays suspended.

However one problem with this is, that I would like my Mouse and Keyboard to be able to wake my computer, which doesn't work with this approach. Is there anything else that I need to change to achieve this behaviour?

**Edit:** Following [@waltinator](https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator)'s suggestion and running

```
sudo journalctl  --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"
```

gets me the following output:

```
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver ModemManager[797]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver ModemManager[797]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[728]: <info>  [1700399225.5159] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[728]: <info>  [1700399225.5160] device (wlp5s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver google-chrome.desktop[3392]: [3386:3415:1119/140705.517391:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(471)] ConnectionHandler failed with net error: -2
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver wpa_supplicant[767]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[728]: <info>  [1700399225.5600] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[728]: <info>  [1700399225.5601] device (eno1): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver dbus-daemon[726]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=728 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --n>
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver dbus-daemon[726]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[728]: <info>  [1700399225.5955] device (eno1): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[722]: Withdrawing address record for 2a02:810d:ae3f:e118:962a:a644:8c82:a55a on eno1.
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[722]: Withdrawing address record for 2a02:810d:ae3f:e118:b74d:d302:7a7f:c2d5 on eno1.
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[722]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv6 with address 2a02:810d:ae3f:e118:b74d:d302:7a7f:c2d5.
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[722]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv6 with address fe80::6395:16a6:7123:8671.
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[722]: Registering new address record for fe80::6395:16a6:7123:8671 on eno1.*.
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[722]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::6395:16a6:7123:8671 on eno1.
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[722]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv6 with address fe80::6395:16a6:7123:8671.
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[722]: Interface eno1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[728]: <info>  [1700399225.6417] dhcp4 (eno1): canceled DHCP transaction
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[728]: <info>  [1700399225.6417] dhcp4 (eno1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[728]: <info>  [1700399225.6417] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed no lease
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[728]: <info>  [1700399225.6418] dhcp6 (eno1): canceled DHCP transaction
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[728]: <info>  [1700399225.6418] dhcp6 (eno1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[728]: <info>  [1700399225.6418] dhcp6 (eno1): state changed no lease
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[722]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.178.55 on eno1.
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[722]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv4 with address 192.168.178.55.
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd-resolved[600]: eno1: Bus client reset search domain list.
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[722]: Interface eno1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd-resolved[600]: eno1: Bus client set default route setting: no
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver wpa_supplicant[767]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver wpa_supplicant[767]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp5s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd-resolved[600]: eno1: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1171]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1171]: Successfully made thread 11544 of process 1639 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1171]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[728]: <info>  [1700399225.6744] device (eno1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 19 14:07:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: r8169 0000:04:00.0 eno1: Link is Down
Nov 19 14:07:08 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Nov 19 14:07:08 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Nov 19 14:07:08 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...
Nov 19 14:07:08 Ubuntu-Oliver suspend[11559]: nvidia-suspend.service
Nov 19 14:07:08 Ubuntu-Oliver logger[11559]: <13>Nov 19 14:07:08 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Nov 19 14:07:08 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 19 14:07:08 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Nov 19 14:07:08 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Nov 19 14:07:08 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 19 14:07:08 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1171]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1171]: Successfully made thread 11576 of process 1639 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1171]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (**) Option "fd" "40"
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (**) Option "fd" "43"
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (**) Option "fd" "44"
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (**) Option "fd" "45"
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) event6  - Logitech USB Receiver: device removed
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (**) Option "fd" "46"
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (**) Option "fd" "44"
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) event2  - Logitech G Pro : device removed
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (**) Option "fd" "46"
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) event7  - Logitech USB Receiver Keyboard: device removed
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (**) Option "fd" "73"
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) event16 - WH-1000XM4 (AVRCP): device removed
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1171]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1171]: Successfully made thread 11577 of process 1639 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1171]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 66
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver acpid[718]: client 1813[1000:1000] has disconnected
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:70
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:71
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:80
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd-sleep[11578]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.026 seconds
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver acpid[718]: input device has been disconnected, fd 22
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver bluetoothd[723]: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver gsd-media-keys[2070]: Unable to get default sink
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) config/udev: removing device WH-1000XM4 (AVRCP)
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:80
Nov 19 14:07:09 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (EE) systemd-logind: failed to release device: Device not taken
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: Freezing user space processes
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: CPU 8 is now offline
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: Spectre V2 : Update user space SMT mitigation: STIBP off
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: CPU 9 is now offline
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: CPU 10 is now offline
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: CPU 11 is now offline
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: CPU 12 is now offline
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: CPU 13 is now offline
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: CPU 14 is now offline
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: CPU 15 is now offline
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: LVT offset 0 assigned for vector 0x400
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C002: Found 2 idle states
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: CPU1 is up
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C004: Found 2 idle states
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: CPU2 is up
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C006: Found 2 idle states
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: CPU3 is up
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x8
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C008: Found 2 idle states
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: CPU4 is up
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0xa
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00A: Found 2 idle states
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: CPU5 is up
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0xc
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00C: Found 2 idle states
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: CPU6 is up
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0xe
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00E: Found 2 idle states
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: CPU7 is up
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 8 APIC 0x1
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C001: Found 2 idle states
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: Spectre V2 : Update user space SMT mitigation: STIBP always-on
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: CPU8 is up
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 9 APIC 0x3
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C003: Found 2 idle states
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: CPU9 is up
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 10 APIC 0x5
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C005: Found 2 idle states
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: CPU10 is up
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 11 APIC 0x7
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C007: Found 2 idle states
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: CPU11 is up
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 12 APIC 0x9
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C009: Found 2 idle states
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: CPU12 is up
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 13 APIC 0xb
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00B: Found 2 idle states
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: CPU13 is up
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 14 APIC 0xd
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00D: Found 2 idle states
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: CPU14 is up
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 15 APIC 0xf
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00F: Found 2 idle states
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: CPU15 is up
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHC error in resume, USBSTS 0x401, Reinit
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 330)
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 330)
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 330)
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: nvme nvme0: 12/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: usb 1-8: reset full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ata5: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: usb 1-6: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: usb 1-7: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: usb 1-9: reset full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: random: crng reseeded on system resumption
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: PM: suspend exit
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd-resolved[600]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver bluetoothd[723]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd-sleep[11578]: System returned from sleep state.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd-sleep[11701]: /dev/sda:
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd-sleep[11701]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd-sleep[11701]:  APM_level        = off
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver bluetoothd[723]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1630]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver bluetoothd[723]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1630]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver bluetoothd[723]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver bluetoothd[723]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver bluetoothd[723]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver bluetoothd[723]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver bluetoothd[723]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: motd-news.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd-sleep[11719]: /dev/sdb:
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd-sleep[11719]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd-sleep[11719]:  APM_level        = 254
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Finished Message of the Day.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth Support.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Device setup in 148729 usecs
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP extensions version v0.96
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP quality report is not supported
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver pulseaudio[1639]: Could not find org.bluez.BatteryProviderManager1.RegisterBatteryProvider(), is bluetoothd started with experimental features enabled (-E flag)?
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver bluetoothd[723]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver bluetoothd[723]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver bluetoothd[723]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver bluetoothd[723]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver bluetoothd[723]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver bluetoothd[723]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver bluetoothd[723]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver bluetoothd[723]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Finished System Suspend.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1171]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system resume actions...
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1171]: Successfully made thread 11804 of process 1639 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1171]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver suspend[11799]: nvidia-resume.service
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver logger[11799]: <13>Nov 19 14:07:17 suspend: nvidia-resume.service
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: nvidia-resume.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system resume actions.
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:64
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 24B1W (DFP-0): connected
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 24B1W (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 24B1W (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): HKC 27E1Q (DFP-1): connected
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): HKC 27E1Q (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): HKC 27E1Q (DFP-1): 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: disconnected
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: Internal TMDS
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1813]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 19 14:07:17 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd-logind[759]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
```

Since I'm new to Linux as a whole I don't exactly know what to look out for. I have updated my Nvidia drivers but the issue is still happening. Any further advice on what might be causing this?

Comment: First step is to put a pin in the timestream with
```
date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >pin.tmp
``` Then, do your suspend thing. When your system is usable again,
```
sudo journalctl --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"
``` This will show you all the log messages since you set `pin.tmp`. Some messages relate to your problem.